# Is WolframAlpha wrong on piecewise differentiation at $x=0$?

Tags: derivatives, wolfram-alpha

I'm differentiating the function:

$${ f\left(x\right) = \begin{cases}{x \sin ( \frac{1}{x}) } && {x\>\ne\>0} \\ {0} && {x\>=\>0}\end{cases} }$$
In my understanding it is not differentiable at $x= 0$, as it is not a constant function so we must use the definition of a limit to differentiate at $x=0$.

[Wolfram says its derivative is $0$ at $x=0$.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=D%5BPiecewise%5B%7B%7Bxsin%281%2Fx%29%2C+x+%21%3D+0%7D%2C+%7B0%2C+x+%3D+0%7D%7D%5D%2C+x%5D)

Where am I wrong?

Comment: It looks like you're right and wolfram alpha is wrong (or perhaps there's a disconnect between the what you mean and how wolfram alpha interprets it).

Comment: This function is clearly not differentiable at $0$. $\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=\sin(\frac{1}{h})$ has no limit when $h\to 0$.

Comment: @Mark Yeah and so Wolfram Alpha is wrong?

Comment: If according to Wolfram it is differentiable then yes, it is wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1323015).  You can get WolframAlpha to return the correct result if you replace `D[Piecewise[{{xsin(1/x), x != 0}, {0, x = 0}}], x]` with `D[Piecewise[{{xsin(1/x), x < 0 || x > 0 }, {0, x = 0}}], x]`.  Using the input `x < 0 || x > 0`  signals to WolframAlpha that $x$ is real, and so the algorithm it uses to differentiate is more robust.  See [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=D%5BPiecewise%5B%7B%7Bxsin%281%2Fx%29%2C+x+%3C+0+%7C%7C+x+%3E+0+%7D%2C+%7B0%2C+x+%3D+0%7D%7D%5D%2C+x%5D) for the correct result in WolframAlpha.

Answer (score 0):

Wolfram is wrong as it is often in similar questions.

$f$ is not differentiable at $0$ as
$$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}$$ doesn’t exist.